# How to send tcp packet direct to server instead of a routing process

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 instance which will accepting some socket connection from the client. What happens is, when I try to connect to server, first it goes to somewhere, instead of coming to my original server and then after routing, a new IP system send me the data. I was wondering if somehow I can stop these routings. I actually need the client IP address which get lost when it comes after routing. I haven't used any ELB for it but still something works like ELB. can I stop these things and get my actual client IP address? I am using socket connection so I don't have something like `X-Forward-For`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't downvote, ask me if anything distracts you. Else if you don't know, you can leave it simple

Comment: We unfortunately have some people in this community who downvote questions they don't understand, without a comment to explain what they believe to be the problem with the question.  The downvote is not mine, but there is a problem with your question: unless you have attached a load balancer, what you have described is not the way EC2 works.  You should be seeing the client IP as the peer address on the socket.  There is no "somewhere" that the traffic goes.  You will need to describe the issue you are experiencing more precisely, with actual (or *valid* example) IP addresses for clarity.

Comment: For private IPs `10.*.*.*`, `172.16.*.*` - `172.31.*.*`, and `192.168.*.*`, show the actual addresses.  For public IPs that you don't want to disclose, you can use the [standard example ranges](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5737/) of     `192.0.2.*`, `198.51.100.*`, and `203.0.113.*`.